# Compare two columns of two files and count the differences

Tags: awk, comparison, multiple-columns

I have two files, tab separated, where I want to compare line by line the values of column 1 of file1 with column 1 of file2 and so forth until n columns.

The comparisons are to count the differences.

Values in columns can be either 0, 1 or 2, for example:

```
File1:

col1 col2 col3 col4
1 1 1 2
1 1 1 2
2 1 2 2
2 1 2 2

File2:
col1 col2 col3 col4
1 1 1 1
1 1 0 1
0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0

Results
2 1 3 4
```

So, col1 of file1 and file2 with 2 differences, col2 off file1 and file2 with 1 difference and so forth...
I have seen many similar questions in AWK but the majority of them is to compare columns and append a column from either files if matches or not, but not count differences.

I believe the comparison of not match from two columns would start with something like this, but from there I am totally lost...

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[$1]!=$1; next}
```

Thanks

Comment: `col1 of file1 and file2 with 2 differences`: Are you sure about this? It is same in both files i.e. `1 1 2 2` values?

Comment: @anubhava you are right. I fixed the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} FNR == NR {for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) a[i,FNR] = $i; next} FNR > 1 {for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if ($i != a[i,FNR]) ++out[i]; ncol=NF} END {print "Results"; for (i=1; i <= ncol; ++i) printf "%s%s", out[i]+0, (i < ncol ? OFS : ORS)}' f2 f1

Results
2   1   3   4
```

A more readable form:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}
FNR == NR {
   for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
      a[i,FNR] = $i
   next
}
FNR > 1 {
   for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
      if ($i != a[i,FNR])
         ++out[i]
}
END {
   print "Results"
   for (i=1; i <= NF; ++i)
      printf "%s%s", out[i]+0, (i < ncol ? OFS : ORS)
}' f2 f1
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have paste available you can do this without storing anything in an array except the output

```
paste File1 File2 |
awk '
    NR > 1 {
        mid = NF/2
        for (i=1; i<=mid; i++) {
            count[i] += ( $i == $(mid+i) ? 0 : 1 )
        }
    }
    END {
        for (i=1; i<=mid; i++) {
            printf "%d%s", count[i], (i<mid ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
'
```

Output:

```
2 1 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

With `getline`:

```
$ cat foo.awk
NR == 1 { n = NF; }
{
  if(NF != n) { print "error"; exit 1; }
  for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) a[i] = $i;
  if(getline < f != 1 || NF != n) { print "error"; exit 1; }
  for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) if($i && a[i] != $i) c[i] += 1;
}
END {
  for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) printf("%d%c", c[i], (i == n) ? "\n" : " ");
}

$ awk -v f=File1 -f foo.awk File2
2 1 3 4
```

Explanation:

- Variable `f` holds the name of the first file, we pass it to awk with the `-v f=File1` option and we pass the second file name (`File2`) to awk as the file to process.
- We set `n` (number of fields) from the first line of the second file. Later, if we encounter a line with a different number of fields in one of the two files we exit with an error message.
- We fill array `a` with the fields from the current line.
- Then we read the next line form the first file with `getline`, which sets the current fields with the new values. We exit with an error message if `getline` fails.
- We compare the fields with array `a` and increment elements of array `c` if a difference is found.
- At the end we print array `c`.

> Note: some awk experts advocate against `getline`. If you prefer avoiding it too, prefer the solutions that pass `File1` and `File2` to awk and store the content of the first one in an array. But if your files are large remember that you could encounter memory issues, while the `getline`-based solution could process billions of lines of hundreds of fields without any problem (but would you use awk in this case?).

Comment: It's good that you provide a warning about `getline` when  you use it, it'd be even more useful if you referenced http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline which explains the issues.

Comment: The statement `getline < f != 1` is undefined behavior. Any given awk could interpret that as `(getline < f) != 1` or `getline < (f != 1)` or something else. Any time you have an expressiion (e.g. `f != 1`) on the right side of input or output redirection it must be parenthesized to be portable to all awks.

Comment: `for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) a[i] = $i` = `split($0,a)`

Comment: `if($i &&` would fail if `$i` was `0` and I don't think it's necessary since you already checked the `n NF`.

Comment: It's better to print `ORS` than `""\n"` because the latter is hard-coding a value that you hope/assume that `ORS` has but would cause the script to fail if you set `-v ORS='\r\n'` or something.

Answer (score 1):

As the values in the fields are single chars (0,1,2), we exclude the headers and pack field values to field number indexed strings without delimiters (for example `a[1]="1122"`) and use `substr()` for extracting char for comparing (`$i!=substr(a[i],FNR-1,1)`):

```
awk '
NR==FNR && NR>1 {                         # process first file, ignore header
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)                    # since column values are 1 digit only
        a[i]=a[i] $i                      # just catenate themem, no separators
    next
}
FNR>1 {                                   # process second file
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        r[i]+=($i!=substr(a[i],FNR-1,1))  # compare field data and count mismatches
}
END {                                     # in the end
    for(i=1;(i in r);i++)                 # loop and ...
        printf "%s%s",(i==1?"":OFS),r[i]  # output
    print ""
}' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
2 1 3 4
```

**Notice:** This only works for single char values, as requested in the OP.